# MySQL GRANT to User@'host' not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-error-1045, connector-net

EDIT: I reinstalled MySQL and this fixed itself. No idea what the issue was.

---

I ran the following commands in MySQL from the command line:

```
1. REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON MyDB.* FROM user@'%';
2. DROP USER user@'%";
3. GRANT INSERT,SELECT,DELETE,UPDATE ON MyDB.* TO user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
4. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The grants for the user are:

GRANT USAGE ON *.* to 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON 'MyDB'.* TO 'user'@'%'

But then I get the following error message when I try to do an update.

```
UPDATE command denied to user 'user'@'somehost' for table 'sometable'
```

Relevant info:

SELECT,INSERT, and DELETE all work properly.

I am using C# with Connector/NET

'somehost' is on the same network as the server (different computer).

'sometable' is in MyDB.

If I log in to the server with 'user' on the host machine, update queries work just fine.

EDIT:

If I grant UPDATE,SELECT,INSERT,DELETE to user@'somehost.net',  UPDATE queries work without a problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a user object defined for `'user'@'somehost'`? MySQL will see that as different from `'user'@'%'` if it exists.

Comment: You bad *bad* `GRANT`, why don't you behave yourself?? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling fixed the issue. Not sure what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

After taking away all the grants, first you should give the usage privilege to the user.

```
GRANT USAGE on MyDB.* to 'user'@'localhost'
```

Usage privilege tells the server that this user is allowed to use MySQL

Comment: If that is the case why would SELECT and INSERT work properly? I guess I forgot to mention that explicitly though.

Comment: If you are not planning to give any privilege then only you need to give **GRANT USAGE on MyDB.* to 'user'@'localhost'** which means you can connect to the server with the MyDB specified.

Comment: @Ignacio, I doubt you have a 'user'@'somehost'. What is **SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'somehost'** return?

Comment: I know I don't have a 'user'@'somehost'. I have 'user'@'%'. What I don't understand is why 'user' can INSERT,SELECT,and DELETE (from 'somehost') without any issues, but UPDATE is denied. All 4 privileges were given in the exact same GRANT statement, and this is the only user (other than root) that I have even created.

The return for "SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'%' is contained in the original question.